# Soliton Moduli Spaces and Homotopy Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, topology, yang-mills, solitons

The four-dimensional $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills Lagrangian is given by $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2e^2}\mathrm{Tr}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$

and gives rise to the Euclidean equations of motion $\mathcal{D}_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$ with covariant derivative $\mathcal{D}_\mu$. *Finite action* solutions $A_\mu$ satisfy the condition that,

$$A \to ig^{-1}\partial_\mu g$$

as we approach $\partial \mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{S}^3_{\infty}$, with $g$ an element of $SU(N)$. These provide a map from $\mathbb{S}^3_\infty$ to $SU(N)$, and are classified by homotopy theory. In [Tong's lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0509216) on solitons, he states without proof that the second Chern class, or Pontryagin number $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is given by

$$k = \frac{1}{24\pi^2}\int_{S^3_\infty}\mathrm{d}S^3_\mu \, \, \mathrm{Tr} \,(\partial_\nu g)g^{-1}(\partial_\rho g)g^{-1} (\partial_\sigma g)g^{-1}\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$$

As I understand them, Chern classes are characteristic classes of bundles on manifolds; **in this case what bundle and manifold is $k$ associated with? How does one obtain $k$ in this case?** Tong states "The integer... counts how many times the group wraps itself around spatial $\mathbb{S}^3_\infty$."

In addition, Tong states without rigorous proof the metric of the moduli space (the space of all solutions to the equations of motion which are self-dual):

$$g_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{2e^2} \int \mathrm{d}^4 x \mathrm{Tr} \, \, (\delta_\alpha A_\mu)(\delta_\beta A_\mu)$$

with $\delta_\alpha A_\mu = \partial A_\mu / \partial X^{\alpha} + \mathcal{D}_\mu \Omega_\alpha$ where $\Omega_\alpha$ is an infinitesimal transformation, and $X^{\alpha}$ are the collective coordinates. **How does one compute such a metric of a moduli space? Why should it be given by the sum of all zero modes?**

**I would prefer an answer which utilizes arguments from differential geometry, and topology.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First let me refer you to Eric Weinberg's [book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=rfvFNI2C7i8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=CL)  where the instanton moduli space is described in more detail.

Principal bundles over 4-dimensional Riemannian manifolds are classified by the second Chern class = Instanton number and the t' Hooft discrete Abelian magnetic fluxes. Please see the following [Lecture notes](http://fy.chalmers.se/~mans/teaching/YM/notes/principal_bundles.pdf) by Måns Henningson.

t' Hooft fluxes are present only when the gauge group has a nontrivial center, thus in the case of $SU(N)$, the classification is according to the instanton numbers.

A compactified Minkowski space,  can be thought of as a four dimensional ball $B^4$, with the boundary points ( at infinity) $S^3$ identified. Thus by the Stokes theorem, the instanton number is given by:

$$ k = \int_{B^4}*F \wedge F =\int_{B^4}dCS(A) = \int_{S^3_{\infty}} CS(A) = \int_{S^3_{\infty}} WZW(g)  $$

Where $CS(A)$ and $WZW(g)$ are the Chern-Simons and the
Wess-Zumino-Novikov-Witten functionals respectively and the last step
is derived from the substitution of the pure gauge condition at infinity.

The local geometry of the moduli space can be understood as follows: The instanton solutions are of the form:$ A_{\mu} = A_{\mu}(X^\alpha)$, where $X^\alpha$ are the coordinates of the moduli space. These solutions are local minima of the action, for all constant values of the moduli  but the action is not extremal when these coordinates are made to depend on time. This time dependence is introduced to study the dynamics of the moduli near the classical solution.

The difference between the action with time varying moduli and time
invariant ones is due to the time dependence of the moduli coordinates,
assuming the time derivatives are small(i.e., by substituting $X^{\alpha}=  X_0^{\alpha} + t \dot{X}_0^{\alpha}$, the leading terms have the least  number of time derivatives thus the varied action must have the form:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2g^2} \int d^4x F_{\mu\nu}(A)  F^{\mu\nu}(A) =  \frac{8\pi^2}{g^2} k + \int dt B_{\alpha}(X)\dot{X}^{\alpha} +g_{\alpha \beta}(X)\dot{X}^{\alpha}\dot{X}^{\beta} +  ...$$

Where the last step is obtained after the integration of the "known" solution over the spatial coordinates.

This action has just the form of a particle moving on a Riemannian manifold having a metric $g$ in a magnetic field $B$. The exterior derivative of the magnetic field can be interpreted as the symplectic structure of the moduli space. The form of the metric taken by David Tong will give exactly the same metric, because, the leading terms in the moduli time derivatives of the Yang Mills action will include a time derivative, thus we are left with the variation of the gauge fields themselves.

This is only the local structure of the moduli space. This analysis will not tell us, for example, if the symplectic structure is exact or
closed. Of course, the global structure of the moduli space requires deeper analysis.

One global property that can be "relatively" easily computed is the moduli space dimension, even if a simple closed form of the solution is not available: The dimension is the count perturbation $A_{\mu}+a_{\mu}$ of a self dual solution $A_{\mu}$ which is also self dual modulo gauge
transformations. Inserting the gauge potential in the self duality
equation, The following condition is obtained (Weinberg equation 10.112):

$$ \eta^{\mu \nu} D_{A \mu} a_{\nu} = 0$$

where $D_{A}$ is the covariant derivative of the classical solution, and 
$ \eta^{\mu \nu} $ is a self dual matrix defined in Weinberg (equation
10.74). To remove the pure gauge direction, there exist another
orthogonality condition to all pure gauge directions:

$$D_{A\mu} a^{\mu} = 0$$.

These two conditions can be combined together into a single Dirac
equation:

$$\not{D}_{A} \Psi = 0$$.

where, the relation of the gauge field perturbation and the spinor $\Psi$ are given by: $a_{\mu} = \sigma_{\mu}^{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \Psi_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}$

This construction converts the problem of counting the number of moduli to counting the number of a Dirac equation zero modes. For the Dirac equation, the number of zero modes is given by the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.

Comment: I've only briefly encountered the Atiyah-Singer index theorem in the context of the Dirac operator and quantum field theory anomalies. Can you provide a set of lecture notes, or another text which focuses on the applications of the index theorem in physics?

Comment: @jamalS There are analogous computations for the monopole moduli space dimension in the following review http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0609055v2 by Weinberg and Yi, and for nonAbelian vortices in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306150v1 by Hannay and Tong. There is a more mathematical review of the instanton and Seiberg-Witten moduli spaces dimension computation by David Bleecker http://milne.ruc.dk/~Booss/A-S-Index-Book/BlckBss_2012_04_25.pdf.

Comment: @jamalS cont. There are more applications besides anomalies such as spinc quantization, charge quantization and fractionalization, Brane charges, supersymmetric quantum mechanics, Berezin-Toeplitz quantization and may be more. I don’t know of a single review comprising all these applications.

Comment: "Principal bundles over 4-dimensional Riemannian manifolds are classified by the second Chern class" This statement looks like it needs for further qualifications. Are you thinking about principal $G$-bundles for some fixed $G$? Which $G$? $SU(2)$, perhaps?
 Currently, I don't quite see how to make sense out of this statement because it seems to fail for $U(1)$-bundles, for instance.

Comment: @Danu Sorry for not being explicit, the mentioned classification result is true for simple compact Lie groups. (The question was about SU(N) but the result is a little more general). A detailed explanation was given in Henningson lecture that I attached but the link is now broken and I couldn't find it elsewhere. However, this result is quite known in the physics literature. Please see Witten in: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0006010v1 page 4 around equation (2.3).

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe I find the claim that you can classify all $SU(n)$ bundles by specifically the second Chern class rather dubious. Witten does not say this; he simply says that that over a manifold of dimension $>2$, "a $G$-bundle has [...] additional invariants such as instanton number", i.e. they are classified by some bunch of characteristic classes. Not necessarily $c_2$.  Are you really claiming that $c_2$ classifies principal $G$-bundles for arbitrary compact, simple $G$?

Comment: @Danu The result is for bundles over 4-manifolds only. I mentioned that in the main text.

Comment: Yes, I realize. I'll have a think about it and see if I can find any counterexamples. The reason I doubt that it's true is because the proof for $G=SU(2)$ is very specific to $SU(2)$. I don't believe it generalizes.

Comment: Some further remarks: (i) The concept of second Chern class doesn't a priori make any sense for arbitrary $G$-principal bundles ($G$ simple, compact). Can you give a (sketch of a) construction for, for instance, $SO(n)$? (ii) The fact that, in your post, you seem to want to treat the characteristic class as a number, means that you're certainly looking for an element of $H^4(M;\Bbb Z)$. An obvious candidate is the Euler class; let's assume we can make sense out of that for arbitrary $G$-principal bundles (at least when $G$ is a classical group, we can use the fundamental rep.). [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] The Euler class is also a natural candidate because it agrees with the second Chern class for complex rank two bundles (which ties into $SU(2)$-principal bundles, which I *know* are classified by $c_2$, which in this case *does* make sense). So let's assume the Euler class makes sense. Then, your claim is that the Euler class will classify arbitrary $G$-principal bundles (again, $G$ compact, simple). Do you agree that this is your claim?

Comment: @Danu The result that I quoted is a theorem. People refer to it as the Dold-Whitney theorem. The original paper from 1959 is available online (please see the original reference in the articles attached in the sequel). I know about this theorem from the physics literature. As I told you, Henningson lecture contained a detailed exposition (although not a proof), but regrettably it is not available today. This classification is also mentioned by Aharony, Seiberg and Tachikawa in https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0318v2 .

Comment: @Danu cont. A formulation (and some explanations) of the theorem (without proof) for a general compact simple $G$ is given in lecture 13 of Ben Mares course (page 2) http://tensorial.com/math/gauge/. This formulation should be a generalization of the original article, which I haven't studied. Although, I have studied the standard theory of characteristic classes and bundle classification; I never got to study these deeper results.

Comment: @Danu cont. The questions you are posing are interesting, but probably too advanced for me. Currently my interests lie in other areas, so please forgive me if I won't be able to give these questions the required attention.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the references! I'll have a look :-)